# .app file not being installed in ios simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to install myhealth.app file on my ios simulator.
As myhealth.ipa doesn't run on simulators i zipped it and took the .app file from the payload.
It keeps throwing the below error. What are my options here??

[image]

Comment: You can't just take an iOS build and run it on the simulator.  Apps need to be compiled to run on the simulator.

Comment: i could just drag n drop the .apk file to an android emulator and the app installed and ran successfully. We cannot do the same for ios?

Comment: No, because it doesn't work that way. For a start, simulator builds are x86 (unless you have an m1 Mac) while iOS device builds are arm builds.